# Make Javascript/ jQuery dropdown menu work in IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, internet-explorer-6

I created a dropdown menu with many ways: Javascript, Dreamweaver Spry, CSS. When tested with my medium-level security IE6, none of them works. IE6 prompted me with security warning.

I tried to open other sites with IE6, their dropdown menu doesn't work as well.

Then I find this site:

http://www.trubus-online.co.id/trindo7/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5083:peluang-bisnis-budidaya-sengon-dan-jabon&catid=54:pelatihan&Itemid=411

Its Javascript/ jQuery dropdown menu works, while other sites do not.

Does it use a hack to bypass IE6 security? How to make my dropdown menu works? I don't want to use "noscript" tag.

The code I'm using is:

(1) CSS Dropdown Menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2RbG/

(2) Javascript Dropdown Menu :
http://jsfiddle.net/Aqbh2/

Comment: Forget IE6! _Please_!

Comment: Most people in my country are still using IE6, there are millions of them, so I have to test every site I make with it..

Comment: Can you show your code? Or a link to either your page or a live example at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: How the hell can people be on the internet and not upgrade their IE6 to IE8? Are they all using pirated Windows? That's the only explanation for not upgrading.

Comment: IE6 is still important to test for and it is still used by many, specially elders and non computer savy people.  @Bayu, you need to put efforts in your question and show some code to get answers. Don't expect anyone to write the whole code for you. You can put your code on jsfiddle.net and then post the link here.

Comment: @Kyle: The code I'm using is:
(1) CSS Dropdown Menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2RbG/
(2) Javascript Dropdown Menu (since I'm new user, I can't post 2 hyperlinks, so please see below):
(replace this with "jsfiddle")/Aqbh2/

Comment: @Annete: Yes, most people in my country are still using pirated Windows. They can't afford the original, since the price is the same as what they earn per month.

Comment: @Huessein: Thanks for your info. The code I'm using is:
(1) CSS Dropdown Menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/f2RbG/
(2) Javascript Dropdown Menu (since I'm new user, I can't post 2 hyperlinks, so please see below):
(replace this with "jsfiddle")/Aqbh2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/hzQaL/ updated to use jsfiddle better:P

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you want to work, you give two examples of a drop down menu, one using CSS and the other using jQuery. In IE6 which one do you want to use?

Comment: It's not a security-issue, IE6 only determines :hover in links, that's the problem. See: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html

Comment: @Kyle: I need to figure out for both of them. I want to use them in different projects. Could you fix it?

Comment: Aha, ok. I am not sure I could, I don't support IE6 as a rule and it has lacking support for anything pure CSS and obviously javascript too. I have been trying but to no avail, I think someone else will be able to offer a better solution than I. :)

Comment: Hi Bayu, i feel you pain with regards to IE6, where i work we still have to "support" IE6 too. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062837/make-javascript-jquery-dropdown-menu-work-in-ie6/5064496#answer-5064496), that should help you on your way

Answer (score 1):

i feel you pain with regards to IE6, where i work we still have to "support" IE6 too.

I have a similar dropdown menu on my site that works in IE6, im happy to share a sample of the code with you:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li> 
    <a href="http://target" id="listlink" title="">Hover over me...</a> 
    <ul class="list">
      <li>This</li>
      <li>is a</li>
      <li>list</li>
    </ul> 
  </li> 
<ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Quicklinks Animation
    $("#menu a").attr("href", "#");
    $('#menu li').hover(
       function () {
           $(this).find(".list").fadeIn(555);
    });
    $('#menu li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find(".list").fadeOut(555);
    });   
});
```

Check it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/HaXaM/3/

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh and not forgetting, you'll need a little bit of CSS `.list{display:none;}`

Comment: @Alex: Hi, I tried your code. IE6 still prompted me with security warning like when I tried my code.

Comment: strange... i'll investigate further.

Comment: @Alex: What I want is like this site (http://www.trubus-online.co.id/trindo7/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5083:peluang-bisnis-budidaya-sengon-dan-jabon&catid=54:pelatihan&Itemid=411), it breaks IE6 security and run the Javascript without warning. Thanks.

Comment: I dont get the warning. upload the warning message screen shot?

Comment: Warning message screenshot: "http://img594.imageshack.us/i/warningie6.jpg/". I have medium-level security in IE6.

Comment: Is that not just a standard IE security message because you're trying to run javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's standard IE6 security message. But the site above doesn't cause that message. So the non-techy visitors can see the dropdown effect without clicking the warning.

Comment: I would never endorse overwriting warning messages, but if you really want to do it, try this: [How to bypass IE security](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/123387-how-to-bypass-ie-security-banner-to-prevent-file-download/). _Use and you own risk_

Comment: I've seen the page. I don't get it, how do you implement it in the website code? Put all "RegWrite" codes in "script" tag?

Comment: Im not going to start trying to hack it to bypass security messages, you're on you own there.